# Show that a subset in $\ell_2$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to show that the subset $A \subset \ell_2 $ is open, where the subset is defined as 
$$ A = \{ (x_k) \in \ell_2 | (x_1 -\frac{3}{4})^2 + \sum_{k =2}^\infty a_k^2 x_k^2 < 1 \} $$
You must take A sequence $a_k$ such that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} a_k = 1 $. I chose  $a_k = 1-\frac{1}{k}$

So far I have defined a function  $f: A \subset \ell_2 \rightarrow (0,1)$

$$ f( (x_k) ) = (x_1 -\frac{3}{4})^2 + \sum_{k =2}^\infty a_k^2 x_k^2 $$

I know that if $f$ is continuos the preimage of the open interval $(0,1)$ must be open too, but at this point it gets tricky, trying to prove $f$ is continuos I get that $f$ must be a Lipchitz continuos function where the Lipchitz constant is given by

$$c = \sqrt{ \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} a_k^2} $$
but $c$ is not finite.

I also have tried to see if $A$ is an arbitrary union of open sets, 
$$A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n$$
so far I have only thought in

$$ U_n = \{ (x_k) \in \ell_2 | (x_1 -\frac{3}{4})^2 + \sum_{k =2}^\infty a_k^2 x_k^2 < \frac{n+1}{n} \} $$

but I think is the same problem, since I need to verify $U_n $is open.

Any help or hint is welcomed, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can’t “choose a sequence.” You need to show it is true for any sequence $(a_k)$ satisfying the condition.

Comment: Actually, the exercise specifies that you must choose some $(a_k)$, but I think is irrelevant for the proof

Comment: Nothing in your statement of the problem says that. Maybe post the full text of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any bounded sequence $\{a_k\}$ the function $(x_k) \to \sum a_k^{2}x_k^{2}$ is continuous on $l^{2}$. To see this note that $\sum a_k^{2}x_k^{2}=\|(y_k)\|^{2}$ where $y_k=a_kx_k$. Since norm is continuous it is enough to show that the linear map $T(x_k) =(a_kx_k)$ is continuous. This is easy and I leave this to you.